# How to read JSON inside script tag on Laravel + AngularJs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, laravel

I'm confused that it failed to use JSON on Angular + Laravel(5.2.11)

My plan is,
1. Convey JSON to a blade file
2. Get JSON inside script tag, and set it to a variable
3. Display each data

I added interpolateProvider to avoid duplicating Laravel and Angular description. But actual displayed data is

I checked the following was display I expected.

```
var json = {!! $contents !!};
```

Controller.php

```
public function show()
{
    $champions = DB::table('Champion')
        ->select('ChampionName', 'ChampionKey')
        ->orderBy('ChampionKey')
        ->get();

    return view('allChampionsPage')->with('contents', json_encode($champions));
}
```

allChampionsPage.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.defaultAngular')

@section('menuItem1', 'When buy')
@section('menuItem2', 'When killed')
@section('menuItem3', 'Where lane')
@section('menuItem4', 'How many CS')
@section('menuItem5', 'Search')
```

defaultAngular.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja" ng-app="itemBuildStatisticsApp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{{asset('/css/bootstrap.css')}}}" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{{asset('/css/default.css')}}}" type="text/css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="ChampionsController as ChampionsCtrl">
  <?php include_once("analytics/analyticstracking.php") ?>
  <div id="container">

    <div id="header" class="middleContentItem"></div>

    <div id="middle">
      <div id="menu" class="middleContentItem"></div>

      <div id="contents" class="middleContentItem">
        <ul ng-repeat="champion in ChampionsCtrl.champions">
          <% champion.ChampionKey + ', ' + champion.ChampionName %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="right"></div>

    <div id="footer" class="middleContentItem"></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var json = {!! $contents !!};

    var app = angular.module('itemBuildStatisticsApp', [], funtion($interpolateProvider){
      $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
      $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
    });

    app.controller('ChampionsController', function(){
      this.champions = json.query();
    });
  </script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look in browser console for errors. You will find angular a lot simpler if you just think of Laraval as a back end api and use `$http` to make data requests. There is no need to have 2 template engines. `json.query()` is most likely not a function also

Comment: Also... angular.min.js must load before your code or `angular` will be undefined when your code runs

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see how to directly convey from Laravel to AngularJS, I applid a way, var json = {!! $contents !!};.  Two templated engines was created on purpose for trying extends blade, it is ok.   Amount of Console error is two,  First, Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module itemBuildStatisticsApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'itemBuildStatisticsApp' is not available, Second, Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line is var app = ....). i consider to suspend because of no advances. I have to foucs learning Angularjs.

Comment: links in console for those errors will explain them or use development version of angular for verbose output. Obviously have some dependency and syntax issues

Comment: Based on your advice, I rewrite a programming, which worked!! 1. typo function(funtion), 2. replace json.query() with angular.fromJson(json)

Comment: See...you are already separating angular dependency on needing laravel for the front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var json = {!! $contents !!};

var app = angular.module('itemBuildStatisticsApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});

app.controller('ChampionsController', function(){
  this.champions = angular.fromJson(json);
});
```